# Include a handlebars template in a <script src=""> tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, handlebars.js, mustache

Creating a tabulated page with many "partial views" which are just each handlebars template wrapped in `<script>` tags. The page is getting a little busy, so I'd like all my templates to live in a folder in web called templates and just include them. The problem is that the template doesn't load on the page when i try to include it but work fine when I put the template right in the script tags.

Here is the script include I'm using:

```
<script id="referral-summary-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template" src="/templates/referrals/referralSummaryTemplate.hbs"></script>
```

For reference I tried changing the handlebars file to a js file that just alerted "hello", and that worked fine. Am I just misunderstading what can be a src tag...as in I can only reference JS files?

`referralSummaryTemplate.hbs` Just contains the template (html with handlebars templating). I need the template to be in script tags so I can `Handlebars.complie()` on click events without having to async get the template.

Thanks.

Comment: http://mdn.beonex.com/en/HTML/Element/script.html

Comment: You could always have the scripts append the script tag with the template type to the body.  You'd have two script tags in the dom, but you wouldn't have to async it.

Comment: Wishful thinking I guess. I can just `php include()` it In the script tag, just thought this would make it a little more succinct. Thanks!

Comment: Some one else might be able to speak to the benefits better than I, but I would think that doing the async requests for the data when you need them might be more beneficial.  If you only request them when you need them, your initial page load would be smaller.  Also, if the requests are cached, the ajax request for the template(s) could get the response from cache.

Comment: Try checking if your script is loaded before running your handlebar code.  For template I'd rather use an ajax request to get them instead of putting them in my html, for the same benefits that you want tu use. The only drawback is that you have to write some lines of javascript to load your templates (but you probably already have theses lines for your data).

Comment: I guess my question for that would be, what advantages would that have? I know that all of the views will be used in this "workflow", so knowing that, wouldn't the asynchronous call to the server just be an unnecessary step? I'll be storing a lot of the data in session until the final "save" operation, where I'll POST. So now I have this client side data waiting on async partial view to come back from the server.